# Sum over Yearweek (string) Vertica SQL

Tags: sql, vertica, moving-average

I am looking to create a rolling average in SQL by summing over weekly values. My issue is that the range that I am summing over are yearweeks and are therefore not considered integer values and so I am having issues setting up the range to sum over. For example:

```
select distinct 
origin,
reportweek, 
t2.date as 'Date',
sum(number1) over (order by t2.date range between interval '30 days' preceding and current row) as 'MovingAvg'

from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on reportweek = yearweek

group by reportweek,origin,number1,t2.date;
```

This query works since t2.date is an actual date but I want to sum over reportweek instead, where report week looks like '2017-20' for example (a string). I am looking to create a moving average considering the past 4 weeks.

Please let me know if I can provide any other information!

Thanks in advance!

I am using vertica SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your '2017-20' strings to dates using something like:

```
... OVER(ORDER BY TO_DATE(reportweek, 'YYYY-WW') 
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4 weeks' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)...
```

Be aware: in TO_DATE you can use either

- `WW` (first week starts on the first day of the month) or
- `IW` (ISO Week: first Thursday of the new year is in week 1)

This depends on how your report week is defined.